# VBScript setting environment variables but executable not picking up them up

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I have the below VBScript (values and names changed)

```
Dim InstanceName

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("USER")
objEnv("PLUGIN") = "plugin"
objEnv("CONF") = "location"

Set ArgObj=Wscript.Arguments
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("path.txt", 1)
AbsolutePath = objTextFile.ReadLine
objTextFile.Close
directory = "C:\Program Files\"&AbsolutePath&"\bin"

executable = directory&"\app-"&InstanceName&".exe"
objShell.CurrentDirectory = directory
objShell.Run Chr(34) & executable & Chr(34), 1, false
Set objShell = Nothing
```

My program uses the environment variables PLUGIN and CONF. However, the first time the program is launched using the script, it cannot find the environment variables. The subsequent launches work fine as the environment variables are already set.

I can see them when I check in control panel even after the first launch but the executable doesn't seem to pick them up.

How can I make the variables be set correctly for the executable the first time the script is run?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they User environment variables though? `Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("USER")`. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/fd7hxfdd%28v%3dvs.84%29) for the different environment variable locations - *"specifies where the environment variable resides with possible values of System, User, Volatile, or Process"*.

Comment: Why would you be setting the User environment. Programs use Process environment. So the behaviour you describe is expected. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listenvironmentexe-list-system-user.html for a program that lists How the process environment is calculated from.

Comment: @Mark how is that blog meant to be any help to the OP? Seen you post it a few times now and it’s worse than links to w3schools! Just point them to the official documentation.

Comment: Because it shows how the specific program's environment is built.

Comment: @Lankymart could you post an annswer so I can mark that it was the solution? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values are not being stored as `User` environment variables. Reading through the documentation you want to make sure that you set the `Environment` property of the `WScript.Shell` object to the correct set of environment variables, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/fd7hxfdd%28v%3dvs.84%29) the values are;

- System
- User
- Volatile
- Process

Would recommend changing the code to use;

```
Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
```

and go from there.

Comment: I used “Process” and it worked great, since I don’t have permissions to set “SYSTEM”. Thanks for the help!